# Django URL weird behaviour

Tags: python, regex, django

I've been trying to code a simple app, and came across this weird issue. Look below, my urls.py, first:

This is my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^(?P<label_slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.tasks, name='tasks'),
url(r'^add-label/$', views.add_label, name='add_label'), # this URL is acting funny
url(r'(?P<label_slug>[\w\-]+)/add_task/$', views.add_task, name='add_task'),
]
```

so whenever I access my third url (/add) it is going to a 404 error page, but when I add something like label/add, it seems to work. Can someone tell me how to fix this thing?

This is what the 404 error page says:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/tasks/add/
Raised by:  tasks.views.tasks

No TaskLabel matches the given query.
```

Comment: The regex in your 2nd url matches `add-label` so it tries to render that view instead of the `views.add_label` view.

Comment: Can you tell me why my regex for that particular view is rendering a view out of its views.

Comment: When a request is made in django, it tries to match the request url to one of your urlconf. Since, `url(r'^(?P<label_slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.tasks, name='tasks')` will be found by django first, the regex `[\w-]+` will match the string `add-label`, thus, django will use `views.tasks`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL `'^(?P<label_slug>[\w-]+)/$'` is swallowing the `/add-label` thinking it's the slug of a task and calls the view `tasks.views.tasks`

### List URL regex in their ascending order of genericity

As a good practice you should always put the more generic regex URLs at the bottom, since the URLs are evaluated in that order

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^add-label/$', views.add_label, name='add_label'),
    url(r'^(?P<label_slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.tasks, name='tasks'),
    url(r'(?P<label_slug>[\w\-]+)/add_task/$', views.add_task, name='add_task'),
]
```

Comment: Can you tell me why my regex for that particular view is rendering a view out of its views.